# R how to get information about listed files in the excel

Tags: r, list, file, attributes, sharepoint-2010

I've digging through the raised questions here but failed to find an answer.

Problem I'm facing is the following:

1. I need to get the list of files which were uploaded to the Sharepoint List - around 3300 items, this I was able to do.
2. List needs to be extracted to excel - also managed to do.
3. Each item of that list has to contain last modification date - here's where I struggle to get the results.

I know that for that I need to use a combination of `list.files` and `file.info` functions, but I'm struggling to get the results.

The following code doesn't work:

```
setwd("X:/")

ls<- file.info(list.files(path = "link",
               pattern = NULL, all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE))
```

Does anyone did something similar and could help me understand what should be the logic here?

Comment: what is the error that you get? could you please give an example datasets? in addition, you have a missing comma after `path = "link"`.

Comment: It's working now, I've made a syntax mistake ... Apologies.

On the other hand I'm facing performance issues. Function connects with "backend" of the SharePoint list where all files attached to each line of the list are being stored. 
As mentioned in the problem statement I'm trying to get the amendment date for each of the files. 
There's around 3000 files, and it's taking ages (approx. 30-45 minutes) to get the view.

Is there any way to make it faster?